Is this a valid usage of `std::atomic<T*>`
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

struct Node{
    int value;
    std::atomic<Node*> next;
};
int main(){
    std::atomic<Node*> ptr = (Node*)0;
    auto t1 = std::thread([&ptr](){
        auto r = new Node{1,std::atomic<Node*>{(Node*)nullptr}};  // #1
        ptr.store(r,std::memory_order::relaxed);
    });
    auto t2 = std::thread([&ptr](){
        Node* r = nullptr;
        while(r==nullptr){
            r = ptr.load(std::memory_order::relaxed);
        }
        assert(r->value == 1); // #2
        assert(r->next.load(std::memory_order::relaxed) == nullptr); // #3
    });
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

Is #2 and #3 guaranteed to read the value written in #1? If it is not, what's the reason here?

Looks like a data race to me, but I'm not sure if it can cause issues in practice. Let's wait for Peter Cordes. :)

For a start, all the use of (Node*) C-style casts make me cringe...

It will read the same pointer value, but it isn't guaranteed that r->value and r->next will have the correct values due to the relaxed ordering.

thread sanitizer can be your friend
https://godbolt.org/z/fs6fdcqeo

Thread sanitizer detects several data races when you use std::memory_order::relaxed, but they all go away if you delete it (uses the default std::memory_order_seq_cst). That pretty much proves that std::memory_order::relaxed is not enough here.

There is an example in cppreference with std::atomic<std::string*> . Quite similar to what you are doing.

@HolyBlackCat From the perspective of a language-lawyer, since the creation of Node in the first thread does not have a "happen-before" relationship with the reading of Node at #2 and #2, the conflicting operation does have a data race. But, I want to hear other views of points. Paging @Peter Cordes

TL;DR No, and if you're even slightly unsure about the answer to any atomic problems, don't use anything other than memory_order_seq_cst.
Threads are finicky. Threads don't agree on what order memory modification happens in. Even though your code looks like #1 precedes the pointer store, and the pointer load precedes reading values at #2, they can in fact be anywhere before or after the pointer load/store from the perspective of each thread.
A simple (but not quite correct) mental model you can use is assume the compiler and CPU can reorder any operations in a single thread unless an operation is explicitly forbidden to be reordered. Relaxed atomics is not one of them, and you have a data race. Data races are unconditionally UB.
Even if we were to consider what happens in practice, this still wouldn't work. You might've heard about how x86/64 have a strong memory model and atomic loads/stores are never relaxed. Which is correct, but compilers really do reorder operations, and unless you can guarantee that doesn't happen (such as using volatile, but please just use correct atomics), you still have broken code.

The fix is to either:

Use memory_order_seq_cst instead. This is always correct.
Use memory_order_release for the pointer store and memory_order_acquire for the pointer load. There are situations where this isn't correct.


A simple (but not quite correct) mental model you can use is assume the compiler and CPU can reorder any operations in a single thread unless an operation is explicitly forbidden to be reordered. However, the store operations depend on the creation of new Node, and the value reading at #2 and #3 on Node* depends on the load operation. How does the compiler reorder the code?

@xmh0511 Hypothetically, the compiler can reorder things around such that the order is: acquire memory, store the pointer, then write the values. Also hypothetically, the compiler can see through all the pointer shenanigans and elide all sorts of stuff.

Hypothetically, the compiler can reorder things around such that the order is: acquire memory, store the pointer, then write the values. This is incredible, did you mean the hypothetical scenario is like the pseudo-code: auto r = malloc(sizeof(Node)); ptr = r; *r = Node{0,{}};

@xmh0511 "did you mean the hypothetical scenario is like the pseudo-code: auto r = malloc(sizeof(Node)); ptr = r; *r = Node{0,{}};" -- Yes, that looks (to me) like one of the things that "relaxed" says the compiler can do. Well, except "placement new" is conceptually more accurate for the last line. The "relaxed" memory order and "guaranteed value" don't get along well.

More importantly, the example code seems rather... artificial. Once you start doing real stuff -- this seems like a linked list type of thing -- you'll run into more possible problems. Either use existing lock-free libraries, or just use mutexes and other synchronization primitives -- they may appear less efficient on the surface, but avoid all those headaches and errors.

It should be fine, since ptr is only assigned once, r will always have the non-null value of ptr after the loop.  reading ptr->value as you do is fine as well.  One thing is missing.  delete ptr; before exiting main().
Since you're using std::atomic<> and only relaxed load/store, you should avoid being so verbose, this will make your code more readable.  Consider this:
int main() {
    std::atomic<Node*> ptr = nullptr;
    auto t1 = std::thread([&ptr]() {
        ptr = new Node{1, nullptr};  // #1
    });
    auto t2 = std::thread([&ptr]() {
        Node* r = nullptr;
        while ((r = ptr) == nullptr) {
        }

        assert(r->value == 1);       // #2
        assert(r->next == nullptr);  // #3
    });
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}


The shorter notation you use defaults to memory_order::seq_cst, not relaxed.
